# Can I reuse ToJSON and FromJSON instances between Data.Aeson and Data.Yaml?

Tags: haskell, aeson

Data.Aeson and Data.Yaml are libraries for working with JSON and YAML, respectively, which have nearly identical interfaces. I have written “Aeson-based” `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` instances for some of my types:

```
import Data.Aeson

data PropertyValue = Nested Microformat | Flat Text
    deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ToJSON PropertyValue where
    toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }

instance FromJSON PropertyValue where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }
```

and while Aeson uses these instances, Yaml seems to ignore them. (Specifically, I believe that Yaml is automatically generating encoders and decoders thanks to the fact that my type derives `Generic`.) I tried to make the instances work with Yaml as well by changing my code to

```
import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Yaml as Y

data PropertyValue = Nested Microformat | Flat Text
    deriving (Generic, Show)

instance ToJSON PropertyValue where
    toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }

instance FromJSON PropertyValue where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }

instance Y.ToJSON PropertyValue where
    toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }

instance Y.FromJSON PropertyValue where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }
```

but GHC complained:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance ToJSON PropertyValue
    -- Defined at src/Microformats.hs:54:10
  instance ToJSON PropertyValue
    -- Defined at src/Microformats.hs:60:10
```

Is it not possible to define instances for two different classes that happen to have the same name? Or is Yaml’s `ToJSON` actually the *same* class as Aeson’s somehow?

More to the point, is it possible to reuse my `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances to avoid having to write the same code twice? Failing that, is it at least possible to write instances of both libraries’ `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` without confusing the compiler?

Comment: It turns out that my *actual* problem was that I was defining `toEncoding` but not `toJSON`, which meant that the auto-generated `toJSON` was being used instead of the code I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: the `ToJSON` (and `FromJSON`) typeclasses of `Data.Aeson` and `Data.Yaml` **are the same**. `Data.Yaml` actually only performs a ***reimport*** of the `ToJSON` typeclass of `Data.Aeson`.

If we look at the [**`Data.Yaml`** source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.29/docs/src/Data-Yaml.html):

> ```
> #if (defined (ghcjs_HOST_OS))
> module Data.Yaml {-# WARNING "GHCJS is not supported yet (will break at runtime once called)." #-}
> #else
> module Data.Yaml
> #endif
>     ( -- * Types
>       Value (..)
>     , Parser
>     , Object
>     , Array
>     , ParseException(..)
>     , prettyPrintParseException
>     , YamlException (..)
>     , YamlMark (..)
>       -- * Constructors and accessors
>     , object
>     , array
>     , (.=)
>     , (.:)
>     , (.:?)
>     , (.!=)
>       -- ** With helpers (since 0.8.23)
>     , withObject
>     , withText
>     , withArray
>     , withScientific
>     , withBool
>       -- * Parsing
>     , parseMonad
>     , parseEither
>     , parseMaybe
>       -- * Classes
>     , ToJSON (..)
>     , FromJSON (..)
>       -- * Encoding/decoding
>     , encode
>     , encodeFile
>     , decode
>     , decodeFile
>       -- ** Better error information
>     , decodeEither
>     , decodeEither'
>     , decodeFileEither
>       -- ** More control over decoding
>     , decodeHelper
>     ) where
> #if !MIN_VERSION_base(4,8,0)
> import Control.Applicative(())
> #endif
> import Control.Exception
> import Data.Aeson
>     ( Value (..), ToJSON (..), FromJSON (..), object
>     , (.=) , (.:) , (.:?) , (.!=)
>     , Object, Array
>     , withObject, withText, withArray, withScientific, withBool
>     )
> ```
>
> (...)

So the module exports a `ToJSON` typeclass, but this is only the result of a `ToJSON` import of `Data.Aeson`, hence the typeclass is actually the very same.

So it is reimported for programmer convenience (you for instance do not have to import `Data.Aeson` only to implement `FromJOSN` for example), but in fact you still work with the same types, the same type classes, etc. After all your `ToJSON` and `Y.ToJSON` refer to the *same* typeclass.

Since the two are actually the same, you can not instantiate the same typeclass twice for the same type, but we do not need to do that: if we implement it for `Data.Aeson` (or `Data.Yaml`), that is sufficient, since the typeclass constraints that are for instance written in `Data.Yaml` (or `Data.Aeson`) will succeed. A consequence is that we can not (at least not without some tricks), implement `ToJSON` differently for `Data.Yaml` than for `Data.Aeson`.